# Determine address size of process within Linux kernel (x86_64)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have to work with the address size of 32-bit and 64-bit processes inside the Linux kernel on x86_64. The possibility to treat with this that I'm currently using is checking task-specific flags. But I was wondering if there is an easier way to determine the address size of a process.

So, what's the proper and easiest way to retrieve the address size of a process within the Linux kernel?

Comment: Define address size. Do you mean the address space, as shown in user land thru `/proc/$pid/maps` ?

Comment: `(sizeof (void*)) << 3`?

Comment: With address size I mean 4 byte for 32-bit and 8 byte for 64-bit processes. This is not about the address space.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/proc/self/maps` and parse for the `[vsyscall]` entry. A 64 bit process will have a 64 bit address, e.g.:

```
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

A 32 bit process won't. I don't have a 32 bit process on hand to provide an example, but it won't have a 64 bit address.

Comment: Parsing doesn't seem to be a better option than checking the task-specific flags. I'm looking for something _easier_.